# Extract only value from key value pair in quotes via Regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string with lines of the format

```
"key": "value"
```

I want to use regex to match just the values without quotation marks (this is for a a bash script).

I tried to create a regex in the lines of "Match second occurrence of all alphanumeric characters within quotes" but haven't been able to make it work successfully.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: It's this JSON? Do you prefer regex over the quicker, easier and more robust `jq` approach?

Comment: Use `jq` for parsing json. If you don't have POSIX regex, but have extended, then a hack would be `grep -E -o '\w+' | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the lines are stored in a variable named `data`, then:

```
grep -Po '^.*".*"\s*:\s*"\K.*(?=".*$)' <<< "${data}"
```

Consider using `jq` instead if this is JSON data.